# jakarta.el.PropertyNotWritableException: Illegal Syntax for Set Operation for the PrimeFaces <p:selectOneMenu /> component

Tags: jsf, el, conditional-operator

Currently we are migrating the Jakarta Faces application from WildFly to Spring Boot v.3.1.1 using JoinFaces v.5.1.1. The version of PrimeFaces is 12.0.0. The implementation of Jakarta Faces is Mojarra v.4.0.2. I've figured out that the following ternary operator for the "value" attribute of <p:selectOneMenu /> component causes `jakarta.el.PropertyNotWritableException: Illegal Syntax for Set Operation` exception: `<p:selectOneMenu id="someId" value="#{checkBoxBean.checked ? anotherBean.filters.value : ''}" />`. The problem isn't reproducible on WildFly-based application. Moreover the problem isn't reproducible if I use the construction like `<p:selectOneMenu id="someId" value="#{anotherBean.filters.value" />` or `<p:selectOneMenu id="someId" value="''" />` in Spring Boot. There is used EL resolver "org.primefaces.application.exceptionhandler.PrimeExceptionHandlerELResolver". However the usage of EL resolver "org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver" does not fix the problem. Is there any way to make EL ternary operator work in JoinFaces/Spring Boot environment?

Comment: It shouldn't have worked in stock WildFly either. The past spec is not detailed in the question and the functional requirements are unclear but I believe that you're looking for something like `<p:selectOneMenu id="someId" value="#{anotherBean.filters.value}" disabled="#{not checkBoxBean.checked}" />`.

Comment: Yes, looks like JSTL doesn't support ternary operator. So finally we have decided to move all the conditional logic from EL to Java code. And that works. Thank you for having looked at that @BalusC.

Comment: There is no means of JSTL here. It's part of EL.